# Is it possible to copy an empty directory using ant ftp task

Tags: ant, ftp

Running in to ussue using FTP task from Apache Ant.  Finding that an empty directory is not being created in the target location. Is there way to force the transfer to create the directory?  this is representative of the task specified in my ant build script.  the first three substitutions  are obvious the 4th is the source directory and the 5th is the target directory.

```
    <ftp action="get"
     server="${Server}"
     userid="${User}"
     password="${Password}"
     passive="true"
     remotedir="${DependenciesDirectory}">
  <fileset dir="${bldSrvDependenciesDirectory}">
    <include name="**/**" />
  </fileset>
</ftp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation of ant ftp and scp task. The simple workaround is to make sure every directory contains at least some dummy placeholder file.

Comment: Thanks, did some research to see if that was the case or if there were options on the task that would allow for it.  your solution is actually what I had tried as a temporary work around.  Thanks again.